# Gridview loads random images

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter

I've implemented the view holder pattern which is meant to reuse items. 
every time i reload the application it loads different images and never the whole list.
I'm using an ArrayList which holds 20 R.Drawable.pic_x

```
public class SetWallpaperAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<Integer> mResourceIdList;
static int mWidth;

public SetWallpaperAdapter(Context context){
    mContext = context;
    initWallpapersList();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    mWidth = metrics.widthPixels / 2 -10;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mResourceIdList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mResourceIdList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// our ViewHolder.
// caches our TextView
private static class ViewHolderItem {

    public ImageView mImageViewItem;

    public void initHolder (View view) {
         mImageViewItem = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.wallpaper_image);
    }

    public void updateView (final int resId) {

        // assign values if the object is not null
        if(resId != 0) {
            // get the TextView from the ViewHolder and then set the text (item name) and tag (item ID) values
            Picasso.with(mImageViewItem.getContext()).load(resId).resize(mWidth,(int)(mWidth *1.5)).into(mImageViewItem);
            mImageViewItem.setTag(resId);

        }
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolderItem viewHolder;

    if(convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wallpaper_item, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
        viewHolder.initHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        Log.d("aaa", "NEW!");
    }else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
        Log.d("aaa", "RESUSE");
    }

    // object item based on the position
    int resId = mResourceIdList.get(position);

    viewHolder.updateView(resId);

    return convertView;
}

/* Static resources */
private void initWallpapersList() {

    mResourceIdList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    mResourceIdList.add(R.drawable.angry_lion);
    mResourceIdList.add(R.drawable.apple_rainbow_fly);
    mResourceIdList.add(R.drawable.apple_returns);
    mResourceIdList.add(R.drawable.aqua_blue);
    mResourceIdList.add(R.drawable.baloon_blur);
    mResourceIdList.add(R.drawable.blur_times);
    mResourceIdList.add(R.drawable.catwoman);
    mResourceIdList.add(R.drawable.clown);
    mResourceIdList.add(R.drawable.cold_kasima);
    mResourceIdList.add(R.drawable.daft_punk_two);
    mResourceIdList.add(R.drawable.geometric);
    mResourceIdList.add(R.drawable.ios7);
    mResourceIdList.add(R.drawable.minion_hitman);
    mResourceIdList.add(R.drawable.night_stars_over_mt);
    mResourceIdList.add(R.drawable.primary_color);
    mResourceIdList.add(R.drawable.prosper_mountain);
    mResourceIdList.add(R.drawable.rolling_stones);
    mResourceIdList.add(R.drawable.shimmer_art_blue);

}
}
```

My problem is that every time I open the app different images load into the Gridview and never all of them. It should be that all of the ArrayList initialized within the initWallpaperList() should be displayed within the gridview. Moreover the list contains 18 items and when the list is initially loaded getView() is called 26 times.

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: like the title says: it loads random images. not all of them.

Comment: Edit Your Question with detail

Comment: your code look like ok please post all code

Comment: please post code of update view

Comment: It's inside the Viewholder class

Comment: code is fine, can you more explain about your problem

Comment: If you could give a small explanation and not only the fix I would like that a lot.